# Failed importing code from SVN to GIT - SVN trunk is empty

Tags: c#, .net, git, svn

I try to clone my SVN (assembla) repository to GIT one (bitbucket)

I used bitbucket wizard importing code from SVN to GIT **online**

But I got the following error:

```
23:58:39 svn import for: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ugisvn/trunk
23:58:39 Checking out https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ugisvn/trunk...
23:58:40 A elad2109/elad2109/bb_tmp
23:58:40 Exported revision 59.
23:58:40 Done
23:58:40 Subversion checkout successful
23:58:40 Creating new git repository...
23:58:40 Initialized empty Git repository in elad2109/elad2109/bb_tmp/.git/
23:58:40 Done
23:58:40 Done
23:58:40 # On branch master
23:58:40 #
23:58:40 # Initial commit
23:58:40 #
23:58:40 nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
23:58:40 Unable to convert svn checkout to git
23:58:40 Svn checkout failed: <class 'bitbucket.apps.async.tasks.ImportException'>: Command failed. Return value: 1
```

But how can I fix it?

**Solved:**

My two problems were solved:

1. `missing Author`  - I had to verify my registartion email to bitbucket.org
2. `empty trunk` - I just gave one higher level of SVN repository

Answer (score 3):

Solved my two problems:

missing Author - I had to verify my registartion email to bitbucket.org

empty trunck - just gave one higher level of SVN repository

Answer (score 2):

Try using the command line. You must fiddle with your authors file. 
Basically for any "No existing author found" you must add a none entry in your authors.txt file

`elad2109 = none <none@none.com>`

Here's a good tutorial on manual migration:
http://taombo.com/taombo-blog/moving-your-svn-repositories-to-git-on-bitbucket

Regards,
Zeno.

Comment: I bypassed the missing author error. I have a new one now. See my revised question

Comment: It's impossible for me to find out what caused the error. The error message is cause by bitbucket's import wizard framework and it's vague. Using the command line gives you better chances to achieve a successful import.

Comment: Solved my two problems:

1. `missing Author`  - I had to verify my registartion email to bitbucket.org 

2. `empty trunck` - just gave one higher level of SVN repository

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Bitbucket's SVN importer works, but based on `23:58:40 # Initial commit 23:58:40 # 23:58:40 nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)` it seems that they have a custom system which uses `git add` and commands like that. SVN supports commits which don't modify any files, whereas normally Git requires each commit to have at least one file. Maybe Bitbucket's SVN importer can't handle empty commits correctly.

It might be best to use git-svn to do the import manually - anyways that is needed when importing unstructured SVN repositories which don't always strictly follow the standard layout. Here are some of my experiences on importing repositories to Git: http://blog.orfjackal.net/search/label/git